# DOCx4j - WordprocessingMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart does not work on server for word 2013 documents

Tags: java, xml, xslt, docx4j

I'm using docx4j 3.2.2.jar to replace the header, footer and a table in the word document. The code use to work fine till I was using word 2007 as the file to be processed.

When I modify the word document and add any shapes using word 2013 the below xml namespaces are generated.

The docx4j fails to write the header, footer and table to the word document on the server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14"
    xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk"
    xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup"      
xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"   xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"       xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing     xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"      xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas">
```

However, if I replicate the same docx4j code on my local set up and provide the file for processing the file is correctly processed. And the below XML namespaces are generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 w15"
xmlns:ns32="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/lockedCanvas" xmlns:ns31="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/compatibility" xmlns:ns30="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography" xmlns:odgm="http://opendope.org/SmartArt/DataHierarchy" xmlns:odi="http://opendope.org/components" xmlns:oda="http://opendope.org/answers" xmlns:odq="http://opendope.org/questions" xmlns:odc="http://opendope.org/conditions" xmlns:odx="http://opendope.org/xpaths" xmlns:ns23="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps" xmlns:ns21="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:powerpoint" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ns17="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2008/diagram" xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:dgm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram" xmlns:ns12="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chartDrawing" xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:ns9="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
```

The below exception is generated on the server while the same code process the file correctly on my local set up.

Error in method

```
getFirstTable!syJavaExceptionWrapper,org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: org/docx4j/jaxb/mc-preprocessor.xslt not found via classloader.!syJavaExceptionWrapper,javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: org/docx4j/jaxb/mc-preprocessor.xslt not found via classloader.<br> - with linked exception:<br>[java.io.IOException: org/docx4j/jaxb/mc-preprocessor.xslt not found via classloader.]!syJavaExceptionWrapper,java.io.IOException: org/docx4j/jaxb/mc-preprocessor.xslt not found via classloader.
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: org/docx4j/jaxb/mc-preprocessor.xslt not found via classloader.
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPart.getContents(JaxbXmlPart.java:154)
    at com.webcenter.content.docx4j.TableUtil.getFirstTable(TableUtil.java:102)
```

Comment: Your sample xml contains the opening tag and namespace declarations, but nothing else.  It is unclear what your question is. Including "wp14" in @mc:Ignorable is likely relevant, but docx4j ought to take care of this.  When you update your question to improve its clarity, please state which version of docx4j you are using.

Comment: Hi JasonPlutext, I have updated the post. Please help.

Comment: As the exception states, "mc-preprocessor.xslt not found via classloader".  You'll need to fix that.  What app server are you using?

Comment: Hi Jason, the code is on the weblogic UCM server. And the docx4j3.2.2 jar is under the lib folder. The same code works fine on my local set up in eclipse. Is the fie mc-preprocessor.xslt not loaded?

Comment: It should be.  Start by verifying it is present in your docx4j jar.   Also browse http://www.docx4java.org/forums/weblogic-f25/ regarding class loader issues

Comment: Hi Jason, the file mc-preprocessor.xslt file is present in the web-inf/lib folder.

Comment: Hi Jason, I have the same issue as the below URL has described. However, I tried setting the class loader but I still get the same issue. Could you please help me on this. http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/convert-to-bytearrayoutputstream-t1736.html